# Minipage after paracol overflows instead of starting a new page

Tags: minipage, paracol

I have a `minipage` that is placed after a section of 2 parallel columns, set with `paracol`. The `minipage` overflows the bottom of the page, rather than breaking onto a new page. How can I get the `minipage` to automatically start on a new page if needed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}
\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.5, 0.5}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \begin{leftcolumn}
    \lipsum[3-5]
  \end{leftcolumn}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
    \lipsum[3-5]
  \end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without paracols, it breaks as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Not only does the minipage not break to a new page, it's indented.  For that problem, try adding `\noindent` before `\begin{minipage}`; if on a separate line, don't leave a blank line between them.  (Sorry, have no idea about the page break problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you gave us no documentclass you are using so I guess class `report`. Then I can reproduce your issue.

But I do not understand what you want to do with that `minipage` ... If you only want to add an block of text layouted in **one** column simply use the environment `\begin{paracol}{1}` like in the following mwe (please see that I added option `showframe` to `geometry` to get the typing area and margins visualized and I marked important code changings with `<======`):

```
\documentclass{report} % <==============================================

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}


\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.5, 0.5}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \begin{leftcolumn}
    \lipsum[3-5]
  \end{leftcolumn}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
    \lipsum[3-5]
  \end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}

\begin{paracol}{1} % <==================================================
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

As you can see the new paragraph in only one column is intended, there is a page break where it is needed (second red arrow in the image) and the text is continiued on the next page.

That seems to be what you want to get ...

If that is not what you need please complete your given code with your used documentclass and perhaps can you add an sketch of the result you want to get?

If you insist in the `minipage` (please see a minipage can **not span** two pages!) you can use for example `\newpage` to get it moved on the next page, but of course with a great white space on the page before.  Do not forget then to use `\noindent` ...

See the second mwe for this case too:

```
\documentclass{report} % <==============================================

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}


\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.5, 0.5}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \begin{leftcolumn}
    \lipsum[3-5]
  \end{leftcolumn}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
    \lipsum[3-5]
  \end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}

\begin{paracol}{1} % <==================================================
  \lipsum[1-8] % <============================== to force minipage to next page ...
\end{paracol}

\newpage  % <===========================================================
\noindent % <===========================================================
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \section{test} % <====================================================
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting second pdf with white space]

Please see that you lost the indention of the first line of a new paragraph in the minipage ...

For me it seems the first code results in a better result ...

Comment: Thanks for the response. My document class line was cut off by the code formatting. I fixed that (it is `article`). This is a MWE. My real `minipage` is more complicated, with images/paragraphs/background color that need to ride together (sort of a call-out). I am aware that a `minipage` cannot span two pages, and it does not need to do so. It is not easy for me to manually add a `\newpage` or a `\flushpage` (in the `paracol` env) in this special case, because this document is being used as a template to generate numerous documents with various copy lengths.

Comment: Wrapping my `minipage` in `\begin{paracol}{1}...\end{paracol}` does seem to do the trick though!

Comment: @Joel Ah, I see, in this case (your first comment) it would have been better to include an image and backgrounf to the minipage to make the reason for the minipage clear. Sorry for my missunderstanding ...